# How can I update the value of an instance variable?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I have a class `OrangeTree` and a function `OneYearPasses`. This function is supposed to increment the age and height of a tree by one.

```
class OrangeTree
  def initialize(height, age)
    @height = height
    @age = age
  end

  def age
    @age
  end

  def height
    @height
  end

  def OrangeHeight
    puts "This Orange tree is #{height} unit  tall"
  end

  def OneYearPasses
    age =+ 1
    height =+ 1
    puts "This Orange tree is now #{age} years old and its height is      now #{height}"
  end
end

FirstOrangeTree = OrangeTree.new(0,0)
```

When I try to increment them, it doesn't save the new values:

```
orangeOne =  FirstOrangeTree.OneYearPasses
# >> This Orange tree is now 1 years old and its height is now 1
orangeOne = FirstOrangeTree.OneYearPasses
# >> This Orange tree is now 1 years old and its height is now 1
```

I guess it only returns a new copy.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues there. The first is to increment anything one should use:

```
var = var + 1
```

that might be shortened to

```
var += 1
```

not to

```
var =+ 1
```

The latter is simply read as

```
var = +1
```

---

Another issue is you are messing getters, instance variables and [absent in your code] setters. Your `age` method *reads a value of the variable*. To set it, one should either set the value of the instance variable:

```
@age += 1
```

or declare a setter:

```
def age=(value)
  @age = value
end
```

and use it as shown below:

```
self.age += 1
```

`self` above is mandatory because otherwise, ruby interpreter will create a local variable instead of calling the setter method.

Comment: I swear to god the first thing I tried to make sure of before I started the class is 'is it += or =+' !! .. It gave me an error first so I was like 'Ok, It's =+ then !' LOL .. For the getter issue, I wrote as '@age += 1' first then I changed thinking that it, along other changes, would solve the problem :/ ... anyway Thank you mudasobwa. Thank you very much.

Comment: I would recommend reading docs instead of being like “ok, let’s try to randomly swap a couple of symbols” :)

Comment: @MotlaqAlMutairi it's also a good idea to actually read the error messages – they often contain valuable hints. You probably got a `NoMethodError` saying _"undefined method \`age=' for OrangeTree"_ (indicating that you forgot to implement a `age=` method). BTW you can use `attr_accessor :age, :height` to have Ruby generate getters and setters automatically.

Comment: @Stefan nope, I guess, on `age =+ 1` the local variable `age` was silently created and no error message came up.

Comment: @mudasobwa oh, because it was called without an explicit receiver! What a debugging nightmare :-)